# What is wrong with my xpath? Keep outputting identical snippet for each node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a rather flat table that looks like

```
<tr>
<td class="tableResultsA" nowrap>1</td>
<td class="tableResultsA" nowrap><A HREF="docs/123456" target="_blank">Title</A></td>
<td class="tableResultsA" nowrap>SNIPPET</td>
<td class="tableResultsA" nowrap>Date</td>
<td class="tableResultsA" nowrap>Category</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tableResultsB" nowrap>1</td>
<td class="tableResultsB" nowrap><A HREF="docs/678901" target="_blank">Title</A></td>
<td class="tableResultsB" nowrap>SNIPPET</td>
<td class="tableResultsB" nowrap>Date</td>
<td class="tableResultsB" nowrap>Category</td>
</tr>
```

I need to create a document out of this data, consisting of URL, Title and Snippet.

I've set my root result node to this:

```
<scope>
<xsl:value-of select>"//td[@class='tableResultsA'][2] | //td[@class='tableResultsB'][2]"
</scope>
```

For my document, I have the following:

```
<xsl:template match="//td">
   <document url="{a/@href}">
     <content name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="a" />
     </content>
     <content name="snippet">
        <xsl:value-of select="//td[@class='tableResultsA'][3] | //td[@class='tableResultsB'][3]" />
     </content>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem is the snippet.  I'm getting the exact same result in my snippet output so it isn't traversing the data.  I'm not an XPath expert.  I'm wondering if following or following-sibling would work but I haven't been able to find a good example for them anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `<scope>` block is not valid XML... Also, which XML/XPath processing system are you using?

Comment: Your XPath in your second XSLT snippet will always output the value of the 3rd `tableResultsA` `td`.  What is the expected output?  Also, your input XML isn't valid XML.  Attributes can't stand on their own the way you have `nowrap` there.

Comment: Jim, thanks.  Did not know this.  FYI, I'm not using the scope attribute within my template.  I'm using an application specific attribute and thought that scope was the closest attribute to convey meaning.

Comment: JL, the expected output is to display the respective snippet data within the respective table.  The order goes tableResultsA, tableResultsB, tableResultsA and so on.  THat's how the web page has the results list set up - within two alternating tables.  I'll check about the 'nowrap', but I'm not sure if that really matters.  I'm just trying to make sure I get the output for the snippet in each respective node.  Hope I'm explaining this clearly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="tr">
  <document url="{td/A/@HREF}">
     <content name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="td/A"/>
     </content>
     <content name="snippet">
        <xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/>
     </content>
  </document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the corrected (to become well-formed XML document) provided input:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableResultsA" nowrap="nowrap">1</td>
        <td class="tableResultsA" nowrap="nowrap">
            <A HREF="docs/123456" target="_blank">Title</A>
        </td>
        <td class="tableResultsA" nowrap="nowrap">SNIPPET</td>
        <td class="tableResultsA" nowrap="nowrap">Date</td>
        <td class="tableResultsA" nowrap="nowrap">Category</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableResultsB" nowrap="nowrap">1</td>
        <td class="tableResultsB" nowrap="nowrap">
            <A HREF="docs/678901" target="_blank">Title</A>
        </td>
        <td class="tableResultsB" nowrap="nowrap">SNIPPET</td>
        <td class="tableResultsB" nowrap="nowrap">Date</td>
        <td class="tableResultsB" nowrap="nowrap">Category</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<document url="docs/123456">
   <content name="title">Title</content>
   <content name="snippet">SNIPPET</content>
</document>
<document url="docs/678901">
   <content name="title">Title</content>
   <content name="snippet">SNIPPET</content>
</document>
```